# D3.js v4 Filled Map Tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, tooltip

I'm performing a join of a US county shapefile JSON (from viz.js.org) to a CSV file to show nomination counts by county. I'm subsetting the data to show only Colorado. Since the shapefile (viz.maps.uscountyurl) doesn't actually have county name, **the tooltip to show County, Count, etc. isn't working**. My CSV does have the county name ("NAME"). I realize it would be much easier with one data source, but I'm not sure how to easily productionalize since the nomination data will be changing.

[image]

Full Code: https://github.com/datavizhokie/colmap/blob/master/index.html

The tooltip is set up on line 130. Cheers!

Comment: Could you put this in a fiddle or something we can play around with?

Comment: @RyanMorton https://jsfiddle.net/fkbjmokx/5/   It's not showing the svg which is weird since it shows in Firefix/chrome1 local.

Comment: Ok, that's the same problem I had when I tried to create a fiddle with your code.  There may be multiple problems. Upon inspection, it throws an error that `viz` is not defined.

Comment: Where is `viz` coming from?

Comment: @RyanMorton thanks for looking into this. http://vizjs.org/viz.v1.2.1.min.js works for me, but I wonder if the issue is that it is not HTTPS.